# Darknet yolov2を使用した動画認識の質問

Tags: python, c, ubuntu, opencv

動画認識に挑戦している初心者です。環境はUbuntu 16.04LTSを使用しています。
以下のサイトに記載されているように、CUDA、OpenCV、Darknetをそれぞれインストールし、ｍｐ４ファイルを指定してコード実行したのですが、エラーがでてしまいました。
何か解決方法はありますでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/

```
$ ./darknet detect cfg/yolo.cfg yolo.weights data/videoplayback.mp4
layer     filters    size              input                output
    0 conv     32  3 x 3 / 1   608 x 608 x   3   ->   608 x 608 x  32
    1 max          2 x 2 / 2   608 x 608 x  32   ->   304 x 304 x  32
    2 conv     64  3 x 3 / 1   304 x 304 x  32   ->   304 x 304 x  64
    3 max          2 x 2 / 2   304 x 304 x  64   ->   152 x 152 x  64

省略

   29 conv   1024  3 x 3 / 1    19 x  19 x1280   ->    19 x  19 x1024
   30 conv    425  1 x 1 / 1    19 x  19 x1024   ->    19 x  19 x 425
   31 detection
mask_scale: Using default '1.000000'
Loading weights from yolo.weights...Done!
Cannot load image "data/videoplayback.mp4"
STB Reason: can't fopen
```

Answer (score -1):

このコマンドを試してみてください（コマンド最後は自分の動画の場所）
./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolo.cfg yolo.weights video_file

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。頂いたコマンドを試したのですが、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいました。

Demo needs OpenCV for webcam images.

Comment: makeする際にmakefileのOPENCVを1にしていないからかもしれません。